# Structuring a fabric project with namespaces

Tags: python, namespaces, fabric

I use fabric more and more frequently now, and I love it. So far, my fabric scripts tend to be relatively short and ad-hoc. It gets the job done and it's fine. That's what I like about it compared to more elaborate tools out there.

I am now trying to bunch together a collection of scripts and want to make them more accessible and easy to use. [Namespaces](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/tasks.html#namespaces) seems like the way to go and it looks simple and elegant.

Currently, the missing piece of the puzzle for me is where to place various **templates and configuration files** that different fabric tasks need (and some might share), and also how to **share functions or tasks** between submodules.

Do I need to set up some `PYTHONPATH` or modify the system's path to make those accessible from all submodules? Is there a recommended structure (or a best-practice guide) for building such fabric project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mostly use regular python imports to accomplish this.

For example, if your directory structure is this:

```
mytoplevel/
├── __init__.py
├── mydeploymenttasks.py
└── templates
    ├── __init__.py
    └── mytemplate.mak
```

Your template can be obtained using something like this:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.resource_filename('mytoplevel.templates',mytemplate.mak)
```

But since tasks live in regular python modules, you can simply import them using your package's structure:

```
from mytoplevel.mydeploymenttasks import installApplicationTask
```

As to how you would structure your package, this depends on its domain. If you find a certain topic grows in your code, break it off into it's own module.

Comment: Thanks. The second part with the python modules works great, but I'm still not entirely clear about `pkg_resources` (never used it and the documentation seems confusing and rather specific to packages)...

Comment: Thanks again @Jasper. The coin has (kinda) dropped. Perhaps a very basic/silly question, but what if I don't want to install it as a package but just run directly from source? if I try to access this from within `mytoplevel` folder itself, it refuses to recognize `mytoplevel` with `No module named mytoplevel.something...` error message

Comment: Yes, in that case you should use a relative import, so in `mytoplevel` you would use `from mydeploymenttasks import installApplicationTask`