# Fabric namespacing wants a fabfile

Tags: python, namespaces, fabric

I'm working through the basic tutorial on [Fabric Namespaces](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/usage/tasks.html?highlight=namespace#namespaces).

I was hoping to do something similar to [Structuring a fabric project with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574580/structuring-a-fabric-project-with-namespaces)

My `__init__.py` file looks:

```
from fabric.api import task

@task
def abc():
   pass
```

When I run `fab --list` I get this error:

```
me@galvatron:/tmp/fabric_test$ fab --list

Fatal error: Couldn't find any fabfiles!

Remember that -f can be used to specify fabfile path, and use -h for help.

Aborting.
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The folder still needs to be named fabfile, as [per the docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/usage/fabfiles.html#fabfile-discovery), unless you specify:

```
$ fab -f myfolder -l
```

Comment: No worries, it's a pretty small section that makes that clear. The docs are thorough, but terse and quite dense in how much they convey in a single sentence, in a few spots.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. I followed the docs http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/fabfiles.html#fabfile-discovery, build a module named `fabfile` and in it i've put different fabfiles, but when i tried to run `fab -l` i got an error `Fatal error: Fabfile didn't contain any commands!`.

To solve this issue i had to import all fabfiles in `fabfile/__init__.py`, like so:

```
from myfab_1 import *
from other_fab import *
from other_tasks import *
```

after this, i could do `fab -l` and got a list of all tasks in all the files. Calling `fab some_task` started working as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was just playing with fabric too, and the docs are pretty thin.

for fabric to pickup your new functions to be used without -f you need to have them defined inside a file called fabfile.py  so try putting your functions in this file, delete all other files, then 'fab abc' should work great!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a file with any other name other than fabfile, ex: filename.py

My filename.py contains content:

```
def hello():
    print ("Hello world")
```

You have to execute command like this:
`fab -f pathToFile methodnameInside.`

Example: `fab -f filename.py hello`